# Maximum size of RAM sticks?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I just bought an [ASUS M5A88-V EVO](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_AM3Plus/M5A88V_EVO/) motherboard and it says that it supports up to 16GB of RAM. I also bought two 8GB sticks of memory.  Will this work with my motherboard or do I need to get four 4GB sticks if I want 16GB?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the results below:

http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/listparts.aspx?model=M5A88-M%20EVO&Cat=RAM

You are limited to 4GB x 4. i.e. It doesn't look like your board supports 8GB sticks.

[image]

Comment: Also make sure you install a 64-bit OS to support all that ram!

Comment: I'd guess this is right. If you look at the QVL from Asus' website for this board, none of the supported configurations it shows has DIMMs larger than 4GB: http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_AM3Plus/M5A88V_EVO/#MSL

Answer (score 1):

Always a good idea to read the manual first. This motherboard's specs are at:
http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_AM3Plus/M5A88V_EVO/#download

The section on memory configurations, says:
You may install 512MB, 1GB, 2GB, and 4GB unbuffered ECC and non-ECC DDR3 DIMMs into the DIMM sockets.

So unless the manual was written before 8GB DIMMs were available and they opted not to mention the then hypothetical sizes, looks like they are not supported. Of course, they still may work - either with their complete 8gb range or just 4gb of them.
You should update your question when you discover the bleeding edge results.

Comment: Doh! I wasted two minutes trying to copy text from the PDF. I don’t know why they block that, all it does it to annoy. `:-|`

Comment: @Synetech Add a text-only printer that defaults to print-to-file. Send your PDF there, then you have the text.

Comment: Thanks; that’s a good tip. However for a couple of lines like here, even that’s far more work than `Ctrl+C`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the [manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM3+/M5A88-V_EVO/E6530_M5A88-V_EVO.zip)? Page 2-11 is pretty clear about what you can use:

> #### 2.4.2 Memory configurations
>
> You may install 512MB, 1GB, 2GB, and 4GB unbuffered ECC and non-ECC DDR3 DIMMs into the DIMM sockets.

You will need to return your 8GB sticks and exchange them for 4GB sticks.

Comment: ... and exchange them for 4gb sticks and some change. It looks like a 8gb stick is about US$65, and 2 x 4GB is US$35 on Amazon. And like @ekaj mentioned, why bother with more than 8gb on a desktop machine?

Comment: Super Photoshop? Ultra BOINC? Games? ☺